# Microsoft Incremental Linker has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, error-handling

I am trying to create a program in visual studios and sometimes the error 'Microsoft Incremental Linker has stopped working' pops up and asks to check online for a solution or close the program.

If I click close the program and rebuild the project it builds fine.

Is there something wrong with visual studios?

Comment: there are definitely some bugs in the linker. You might want to upgrade to VS 2012

Comment: i just installed this version. i know its old but it does the job

Comment: Did you apply Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 and the subsequent updates?

Comment: how do i do that? i just installed the cd

Comment: You can download the service pack [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986).

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem in VS10 (I also have VS8 on the same machine).

Installed VS8 SP1, restarted computer, and the problem is now gone.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hot fix available for this issue. You can check it [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=11399)

Installing this fixed the issue for me.